# using Windows store app DLL in UMDF driver

Tags: windows-runtime, umdf

I have a Windows store DLL which gets the image from the camera device. I want to use this DLL in my driver file[UMDF 2] to get the image. Since the DLL is windows store based DLL, it cannot be directly used in the the driver project. What is the best way to use the Windows store DLL in the UMDF driver ?